# Equation in Noether's paper

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, conservation-laws, notation, noethers-theorem

When I was reading the paper by Emmy Noether about the famous *Noether Theorem*, there is an equation I don't know its meaning and why it holds on page 5.
$$\phi\frac{\partial^{\sigma} p(x)}{\partial x^{\sigma}} = (-1)^{\sigma}\frac{\partial^{\sigma} \phi}{\partial x^{\sigma}}p(x)\ \textbf{mod Divergences}$$
I don't know what "mod Divergences" means in the equaiton and why this equation holds. Can someone tell me?

References:

1. https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0503066

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Divergences* here mean terms of the form $$\sum_{\mu=1}^n\frac{\partial F^{\mu}(x,\phi(x), \ldots)}{\partial x^{\mu}}.$$

The equation is a consequence of applying Leibniz rule (multiple times). Under an integral sign, the equation represents integration(s) by parts modulo boundary terms.